# How to remove an empty area in angular table material?

Tags: css, sass, angular-material, sticky

I am creating a data table with angular material. The default rows showing in the table are 100 rows. When i want to show then 50 rows (through angular pagination). The filtered data leave an empty space. How can i delete this space ? i think the sticky table header cause this issue.

Comment: Can you show some sample??

Comment: Share your sample code?

Comment: can you share stackblitz which replicates the behavior that you're experiencing

Comment: @Pimpale, Singh and lqbal thanks for replay. my code is unfortunately private but i can show you a screenshot for this issue